# AngularJS + Grunt, how to add template file for live reload?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, bower

I would like to ask, where is should to add template file, so after the template change is automatically page reloaded.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of livereload do you use ? The grunt-contrib-livereload ? The Livereload browser plugin ?

- If you use `grunt-contrib-livereload`:
  This plugin is deprecated. You should use the new one that is called `grunt-contrib-watch`
- If you already use `grunt-contrib-watch plugin`:
  Set the `files` [option](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#files) to make your grunt task watch the file you want.
  Then there is a livereload [option](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#optionslivereload) that you can enable (set it to true) to send a livereload command automatically.

In both cases, the location where you add the template doesn't matter. It's the way you configure your watch or livereload that will determine if the template is watched or not.

- If you use a browser plugin :
  Depending the plugin, you'll have to install the plugin and/or install a livereload package for your code editor (example for Sublime Text, you'll have to install the livereload client plugin from the ST packages and the livereload server plugin for chrome/FF/... Then every save in the editor will send a livereload command)